Why does Spring Boot's build-image task download some shady third-party JDK instead of OpenJDK?
When I run spring-boot:build-image in a Spring Boot project, I notice that the container build script downloads something called BellSoft Liberica JRE:
[INFO]     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica JRE 21.0.4: Contributing to layer                                                                                                                 
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/21.0.4+9/bellsoft-jre21.0.4+9-linux-amd64.tar.gz

I have never heard of this company to be honest. What does Spring use this strange JRE distribution instead of something like Eclipse Temurin, which also has Docker images for all Java versions?
The reason I'm asking is that if often fails to download and just caught my attention. I'm just curious what is the advantage of using  JRE builds from this company.

There is nothing "shady" about BellSoft Liberica.

Had to lol at BellSoft being called “shady” :)

tl;dr
Nothing “shady” here.
Liberica is a line of well-built well-tested JDK products from BellSoft, a company that has been an important member of the Java community for years.
Liberica products are built largely from the same OpenJDK codebase as Eclipse Temurin.
OpenJDK is source code, not a product
OpenJDK is a project dedicated to producing an open-source implementation of the Java specifications, along with ancillary sub-projects. The OpenJDK project is owned by Oracle, and operates in cooperation with major contributors such as IBM and Apple, and others.
Understand that the OpenJDK project produces only source code, not binaries or installers. You can use their source code to produce your own binaries and installers if you wish (per the license terms). But you’ll likely find it more convenient to obtain binaries and installers from a vendor.
BellSoft is one of several JDK vendors
Fortunately you have a choice of several vendors offering JDK/JRE products. Most of these products are based largely, if not entirely, on the codebase provided by the OpenJDK project. These vendors include, in no particular order:

SAP
Azul Systems
Adoptium of the Eclipse Foundation
BellSoft
Oracle
Amazon
IBM
Red Hat
Microsoft

… and more.
Oracle’s license terms permit vendors to use the trademark OpenJDK in the name of their JDK products. Some vendors do so, and some do not. The presence of that trademark in the name carries no extra weight, and does not signify any more or less legitimacy.
Liberica is one of several JDK products
To my knowledge, there is nothing “shady” nor “strange” about the BellSoft company or products. They have been an active member of the Java community for many years. Their Liberica JDK products are widely used AFAIK.
In particular, BellSoft makes an edition of their JDK products where they include a copy of the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries: LibericaFX.  Some folks including me find this bundle quite handy. Only one other company besides BellSoft offers such a bundle to my knowledge, Azul Systems with their ZuluFX products.
You said:

something like Eclipse Temurin

Eclipse Temurin is just like Liberica by BellSoft.

Temurin is a line of JDK products based largely on the OpenJDK codebase, from the Adoptium project housed at the Eclipse Foundation, available at no cost, and comes in both JDK & JRE editions.
Liberica is a line of JDK products based largely on the OpenJDK codebase, from the BellSoft company, available at no cost, and comes in both JDK & JRE editions.

I cannot imagine why you would consider one “shady” and the other not.
FYI, the Liberica products offer one major advantage over Temurin: You  can buy commercial support services from BellSoft. Ditto for some of the other JDK products from other vendors.
You said:

I have never heard of this company to be honest.

You may want to keep up more with the industry, if you are a professional developer. Read the industry press, visit a conference, attend user groups.

Spring Boot's spring-boot:build-image Maven goal does not download any JDK/JRE. Spring Boot provides an integration to Cloud Native Buildpacks, using buildpacks from the Paketo project by default. Buildpacks make the decision about whether a JDK or JRE is needed and which one to download. As others have mentioned, Bellsoft is far from shady, and is the JRE that Paketo has chosen as its default. Paketo provides other options that you are free to use.
If you would prefer to use a JRE from Eclipse, you can follow the Spring Boot documentation and configure the Maven plugin like this:
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <buildpacks>
                            <buildpack>paketobuildpacks/eclipse-openj9</buildpack>
                            <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java</buildpack>
                        </buildpacks>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

